# Checking for association between two multi level categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, inference

As part of a personal journey to learn inferential statistics, I am trying to understand if and how income levels influence political views, using data from the general Social Survey (GSS) found [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_8abbe344133a7a8c98cfabe01a5075c2_gss.html?Expires=1696377600&Signature=dlXtpqO3d9f7U7ZOZteH8h2GH7XOayYUm7SkNkbmJ9aC%7ETF1jT02IoqjcH-7AqhYuq-gDKIxxi99clHxzNbiJsdOXpW7-7f5-dya73NlHzft4tNzhzkoDm98RrCu0vZlPxKlqGRyezvWRNzOEkM4lpxscC0MOkIGr-t7Zbjy1iA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

I've proceeded as shown below; however, I don't feel like the p value, which is small enough here to show significance, is very useful, because the plots did not seem to show any association (at least not to my poorly trained eyes) and I still can't describe the nature of association.

Therefore, I would like to know how can I better analyze this data to reach my goals?

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(statsr)
library(ggmosaic)
load("gss.Rdata")
#Trying different plotting methods to discern any trend or association
data <- gss %>%
  select(polviews, income06)
data <- subset(data, income06!="Refused")
data <-data[complete.cases(data),]
data %>%
  group_by(polviews, income06) %>%
  summarise(n=n())
ggplot(data, aes(polviews, fill=income06))+geom_bar()+labs(title="Political Views and Income Levels",x="Political View")
ggplot(data, aes(polviews, fill=income06))+geom_bar(position = "dodge")+labs(title="Political Views and Income Levels",x="Political View")
ggplot(data)+geom_mosaic(aes(fill=income06, x=polviews))+labs(title="Political Views and Income Levels",x="Political View",y="Income Bracket")
table <- table(droplevels(data))
chisq.test(table)

Warning: Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table
X-squared = 264.24, df = 144, p-value = 4.043e-09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  I like using plots, but I don't like the first two. William S. Cleveland, who is a leading expert on statistical graphics, has shown that stacked bar charts are not a great method of showing this kind of comparison.

The third plot is (as the code shows) a mosaic plot. I think these should be used more. But, at least for this graphic, I would make one category out of everyone below \$10,000. And you should put the x-axis on two lines (I don't know how to do this in ggplot, because I don't use that).

For statistics, rather than chi-square, I would use regression. I would start with an ordinal logistic regression where the dependent variable is politics and the independent variable is income. (And, for that, I would NOT lump categories of income together, unless they were causing problems with estimation).

Finally, on choice of color, a very good site is Color Brewer. Since income is a single, ordinal variable, I would use one color and change intensity or saturation. R has an RColorBrewer package.  (I know the site for Color Brewer says "for maps" but it is broader than that).

Comment: +1. Strong agreement on colour. Many reasons not to use a rainbow sequence, starting with the common incidence of difficulty in distinguishing red and green.

Comment: my data contained a lot of missing values and observations where subjects refused to answer the questions on income or political views, and I omitted all of these. at what point should I be worried that it is no longer meaningful to draw conclusions from my analysis given the potential biases introduced here?

Comment: That should really be a different question, but, if the missing data are not missing at random, then you don't need much missingness to make things very tricky. And these are almost certainly NOT missing at random.